# Reload a page once in 5 minutes in background

Tags: php, cron

I need to reload the page once in 5 minutes in the background without opening the page on the browser, i have tried using cron but it is not working.

Please suggest with solutions

i have set up cronjob like this

```
  */5   *   *   *   *   php /home/path/to/php/file.php
```

but its not refreshing

Comment: reload page .. cron .. a full explanation would help us give you the best answer

Comment: I need to reload to the page once in 5 minutes without opening in the browser, is there any other option available other than scheduling cronjob

Comment: cron is the correct approach

Answer (score 0):

**use cron**

“At every 5th minute past every hour.”

```
Minute  Hour    Day Month   Weekday Command 

5 * * * * php /homelink/path/filename.php
```

Comment: */5   *   *   *   *   php /home/path/to/php/file.php this is what i am using but it is not refreshing

Comment: have you set email address for the cron. Every trigger it will send an email notification. If receive email means cron is working, then need to check your code. Also you can debug using the appropriate echo's.

Comment: i did before when i test my code without a corn i receive email and for the email address for the cron he should take the current email address of my account i didn't change it please check above i put a picture maybe will be more clear

Answer (score 0):

if you are in Linux you can use a WGET

```
wget google.com
```

In windows PowerShell

```
Invoke-WebRequest -URI http://www.google.com
```