# php cron job not working

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I try to create a cron job in my hosting on **godaddy** but this cron didn't send any email yet.

that how i did the cron job:

1-login into my account in **godaddy.com**

2-go to cpanel

3-enter in cron job

4-on add new cron job Common Settings i select each minute

5-**Command**:i put like this: **/usr/local/bin/php -q/home/username/public_html/testcron.php**

The code in testcron.php this is:

```
$to="email address";
$from="auto_responder@webinstrect.com";
$subject='Testing Cron';
$message='<h2>Cron is working remove test cron job now.</h2>';
$headers="From:$from\n";
$headers .="MINE-Version:1.0\n";
$headers .="Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

I test this page alone without a cron i receive an email in my junk folder

also i tired to write the **Command** like this: **home/username/public_html/testcron.php**

The problem that i didn't receive any email. Any suggestion to solve this problem ?!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running your command (`usr/local/bin/php -q/home/username/public_html/testcron.php`) from the terminal? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with what you're doing ( except for that there's no space between -q and /home in your command)

Comment: @Wssim Gr you mean the space between php -q should be php-q ??!

Comment: No it should be `usr/local/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/testcron.php`

Comment: i will test it and tell you

Comment: also i didn't receive any email :(

Comment: any other suggestion ??!!

Answer (score 0):

**cron**

"At every minute"

```
Minute  Hour  Day  Month  Weekday  Command  

1       *     *    *      *        php /home/username/public_html/testcron.php
```

[Reload a page once in 5 minutes in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36169908/reload-a-page-once-in-5-minutes-in-background/36169973#36169973)

Comment: have you set email address for the cron. Every trigger it will send an email notification. If receive email means cron is working, then need to check your code. Also you can debug using the appropriate echo's.

Comment: i did before when i test my code without a corn i receive email and for the email address for the cron he should take the current email address of my account i didn't change it please check above i put a picture maybe will be more clear

Comment: For debugging: cPanel under crons section, you can set an email address to receive notification whenver cron runs.

Comment: Try command without trailing spaces= php /home/username/public_html/testcron.php

Comment: I update the email for receive notification you mean change that usr/local/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/testcron.php to php /home/username/public_html/testcron.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128788/discussion-between-m7md-and-devs).